# Перенос сайта с хостинга на Денвер

Tags: denwer, php

Скачал рабочий скрипт с хостинга и не могу его поднять на денвере. В чём может быть проблема? Сервер Unix.

Comment: Проблема в коде с курлом (могут различаться версии, SSL и т.д.). Выпишите курловый код

Answer (score 1):

Очень важно знать что именно он сообщает при работе (при неработе).

Навскидку: в денвере многих библиотек нет, их можно скачать с официального сайта денвера.
Так что смотрите какие он не находит функции, ищите их на сайте [php.net](http://php.net), выясняйте какие им нужны библиотеки и подключайте.

Ах да, не забудьте перезагрузить денвер и прописать нужные реквизиты доступа к БД.

Comment: Caught Exception: Internal Error
Response Status Code: 0
Error Code: 
Error Type: 
Request ID: 
XML: RequestId: , ResponseContext: , Timestamp: 
ResponseHeaderMetadata:

вот ошыбка.
базы нет.там запрос отправляетса